# Remote Desktop Administration of AD DC DNS

Tags: linux, windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, remote

I have an Active Directory Domain Controller that our organization uses.  It also handles DNS.  Administrators are allowed to add names to the DNS records.

Currently an administrator is having trouble using the ADDC for DNS, which they connect through their linux machine to the DC and then attempt to launch the DNS panel the server reports that no DNS is running.  Other management functionality works including gpo and users and computers.

Administrators running on windows have not had this problem, and another linux user has also not encountered it.  I'm pretty stumped about what it could be at this point.

Comment: so Linux > RDP > DC > DNS Manager. Is that the correct action they are taking?

Comment: They are connecting over RDP to the domain controller, then launching the DNS panel through the server manager.  They are then being told that no DNS server is running, adding it by IP, pointing it to the loopback, etc all fail.

Comment: Do they have the same permissions as the users that work? IE the other admins and linux user?

Comment: Does the DNS manager list the same error?

Comment: They have the same permissions and group memberships as the other Admins, the DNS manager simply fails to connect to a DNS server and presents an empty panel.

Comment: The question is "A domain admin, logged on a DC cannot use the DNS MMC because of 'cannot connect to dns server'"?